# separate query return string and digit in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

beginner Question :
I have query like this :

```
 $arr1 = BillProduct::where('bill_id', '=', $bill->id)->get('quantity'); 
 $arr2 = BillProduct::where('bill_id', '=', $bill->id)->get('product_id');
```

and its return like this :

```
[[{"quantity":15}], [[{"product_id":2}]
```

how can i get just digit like 15, 2 ??
and how get in foreach next to each other? like

15,2
18,3
...
return in 2 variable like :

```
return $arr1, $Arr2;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
if ($arr1->isNotEmpty()) {
    $quantity = $arr1->first()->quantity; 
    echo $quantity; // Output: 15
}
```

---

If multiple use `foreach` loop. Ex

```
$quantities = [];
foreach ($arr1 as $item) {
    $quantities[] = $item->quantity;
}
print_r($quantities);
```

---

**Edit 01**

```
$arr1 = BillProduct::where('bill_id', '=', $bill->id)->pluck('quantity');
$arr2 = BillProduct::where('bill_id', '=', $bill->id)->pluck('product_id');

$result = [];

foreach ($arr1 as $index => $quantity) {
    $product_id = $arr2[$index];
    $result[] = [$quantity, $product_id];
}

print_r($result);
```

Comment: thankyou so much. What if I have two values like arr1 and arr2 in foreach?

Comment: show me the code.

Comment: @MehdiBakhtiari check the edit 01

Comment: @MehdiBakhtiari Wc. accept if helphul

Comment: just one thing . it possible get result in 2 value? now it is print_r($result) and both nomber in there . can get result like print_r $a, $b; ????

Answer (score 0):

### Merge columns of two array

**Starting from PHP 5, it is possible to merge the columns of two associative arrays using the `array_replace_recursive()` function.**

- To achieve this, the result of these two Eloquent queries - Collection class - needs to be converted into an array. --> Can use `toArray()`

```php
$arr1 = BillProduct::select('quantity')->where('bill_id', '=', $bill->id)->get()->toArray();
$arr2 = BillProduct::select('product_id')->where('bill_id', '=', $bill->id)->get()->toArray();

$result = array_replace_recursive($arr1, $arr2);
/*
Result:

[
  ["quantity" => 15, "product_id" => 2],
  ["quantity" => 18, "product_id" => 3],
  ...
]
*/

foreach ($result as $record) {
  $quantity = $record['quantity'];
  $product_id = $record['product_id'];
  // ...
}
```

More information: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace-recursive.php

Comment: thanks but i need return just nomber in 2 variable like : print_r $a , $b;

Comment: So if I understand correctly, the result of both $arr1 and $arr2 would always be only 1 record? In this case, use the "first()" function instead of "get()". Example: `$a1 = BillProduct::select('quantity')->where('bill_id', '=', $bill->id)->first()->quantity;`

Comment: no thats the problem both is arry

Comment: You can create variables from the elements of the array. I don't see any obstacle to this not being a suitable solution. However, I updated my response and showed how you can extract the two columns of the array into two separate variables.

Comment: ok and thanks but how i return that? when I put it 2 in the one line I get server error like this => <br> Utility::total_quantity('minus',$quantity,$product_id);

Comment: In PHP, strings should be concatenated with `.`. Like this: `echo "<br>" . Utility::total_quantity('minus',$quantity,$product_id);`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your product_id does not appear multiple times in the result, you can use the second argument to `pluck()` to assign another column as the key:

```php
$result = BillProduct::where('bill_id', $bill->id)->pluck('quantity', 'product_id'); 
foreach($result as $productId => $quantity) {
    // enjoy life
}
```

You save one query now :)

Comment: this result is like this: {"1":1,"2":1,"3":1,"4":1} and I wanted like [[1,1],[1,2],[1,3],[1,4]]

Comment: a `->map()` will probably fix that; the format you are describing is trivial, but the solutions above use two queries which is wasteful when you can make do with one :). Also, less code.